# How to change UITabBarController's modalTransitionStyle in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uimodaltransitionstyle

I used `UITabBarController` in my apps. I want to use `modalTransitionStyle` for `UITabBarController`.

I have three Views in `UITabBarController` with following codes.

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,viewController3,viewController2, nil];
```

And I changed like,

```
self.tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

But it's doesn't work. How to change it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you want to present the tab-bar controller (ie, everything on screen *including* the tabs) modally, or just the content inside them? If you're not presenting anything modally then changing the transition style isn't going to achieve anything. It's probably going to be helpful if you share the code where you present modally.

Comment: Yes.I mean like that.I want to present all ViewController in UITabBarController. Help!

Comment: Modal view controllers don't work like that: you'll need to use the `UITabBarController` delegate methods to implement custom animations. I suggest you read up Apple's documentation on what a modal view *is*, and how they actually get displayed.